# Querydsl: How to create Query with a subquery which returns a Tuple

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

Im having the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT WHERE (TYPE, CREATION_DATE) IN(
    SELECT TYPE, MAX(CREATION_DATE) 
    FROM DOCUMENT 
    WHERE MEMBER_ID = 107374183 
        AND CREATION_TYPE = 'GENERATED_BY_USER'
    GROUP BY TYPE
);
```

Now im trying to create a mapping of this sql with querydsl but having problems with the subquery. As this subquery returns a Tuple containing two column values im getting the error:

> The method in(Collection) in the type
>   SimpleExpression is not applicable for the arguments
>   (List`<Tuple`>)

This is what i tried so far:

```
QDocument document = QDocument.document;
QDocument d = new QDocument("d");
query()
  .from(document)
  .where(DOCUMENT.type, DOCUMENT.creationDate.in(
    new JPAQuery()
      .from(d)
      .where(DOCUMENT.member().id.eq(memberId))
      .where(DOCUMENT.creationType.eq(DocumentCreationType.GENERATED_BY_USER))
      .groupBy(DOCUMENT.type)
      .listResults(DOCUMENT.type, d.creationDate.max())
      .getResults()
  ))
  .list(DOCUMENT);
```

Anybody a idea how i could implement this sql query with querydsl? Do i need to work with joins maybe?